# Output x twice then y, then x twice

Tags: channel-entries, stash

Excuse the title, couldn't really summarise the issue succinctly...

This is what I need to do...

I have a load of entries from various channels (E). And a series of tweets (T) (which are stored in another channel).

I need to output as follows

(E) (E) (T) (E) (E) (T)...

(also, if T doesn't exist output E).

So every third item that is outputted needs to come from the twitter channel.

I'm using stash but can't for the life of me figure out how to output the content like this.

Any thoughts/suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Dave

**Follow on question**
[Paginate two stash lists in one](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/30879/paginate-two-stash-lists-in-one)

Comment: One possible solution would be to just output (E)'s and (T)'s, giving them css classes to distinguish them, and then use jQuery to weave the (T)'s in among the (E)'s. Are you using jQuery in this project?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply.  However I don't think using jquery is a suitable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This builds on CreateSean's answer, since you're using Stash. You'll need a math plugin and in this example I'm using [Math from Caddis](https://github.com/caddis/math).

```
{!--set main multi-channel entry list--}
{exp:stash:set_list
    name="one" 
    parse_tags="yes"
}
    {exp:channel:entries
        channel="ONE_CHANNEL|ANOTHER_CHANNEL|ETC"
        dynamic="no"
    } 
        {stash:entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:entry_id}
        {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{!--set tweet list--}
{exp:stash:set_list
    name="two" 
    parse_tags="yes"
    parse_depth="2" {!--run 2x to parse the math plugin--}
}
    {exp:channel:entries
        channel="TWEET_CHANNEL"
        dynamic="no"
    } 
        {stash:entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:entry_id}
        {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
        {!--set a number to match every third count where the tweet should be output--}
        {stash:two_count}{exp:math formula="{count} * 3"}{/stash:two_count}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{!--output multi-channel list and tweet list--}
{exp:stash:get_list
    name="one" 
    prefix="st1"
}
    {!--output tweet on every third loop--}
    {if st1:count % 3 == 0}

        {exp:stash:get_list:nested
            name="two" 
            limit="1"
            match="#{st1:count}#" 
            against="two_count"
            prefix="st2"
        }
            {!--if no results, output main channel entry--}
            {if st2:no_results}
                <li>{st1:entry_id} : {st1:title}</li>
            {/if}
            {!--tweet--}
            <li>{st2:entry_id} : {st2:title}</li>
            {!--3rd main--}
            <li>{st1:entry_id} : {st1:title}</li>
        {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}

    {!--otherwise output main channel entry--}
    {if:else}
        <li>{st1:entry_id} : {st1:title}</li>
    {/if}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. See my comment on the previous answer.  I think the same would apply here.

Comment: You're right, so updated answer to output the third entry right after the tweet.

Comment: Yup... this does the job...  I need to use pagination and output a form on the first page so I've had to adapt the code a little, but the core is there... I'll post it as an answer, just for shits and giggles!

Comment: Any ideas how you would paginate these two lists.... I'm limiting the (E) to 5, and (T) 1.. Then  using ajax to load in the next set of entries.  Bugger is it's only paginating the (E) list... tricky!

Comment: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/30772/output-x-twice-then-y-then-x-twice/30777?noredirect=1#comment32811_30777

Answer (score 1):

I would use conditionals and the [modulus operator](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/conditionals.html#modulus-operator) like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="foo" limit=100"}

 {if count % 3 == 0}

    insert tweet here

 {if:else}

    insert entries here

 {/if}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Trouble is the Tweets are stored in another channel. Could use an embed to pull each in and if no results ignore and it continues on it's loop, but this will return duplicate tweets. Hence possibly the reference to stash. Also mentioned multiple channels for the main entries loop.

Comment: multiple channels use channel="foo|bar|etc". for the embed on tweets you could pass in an offset like this offset="({count} / 3) - 1". You'd probably need a math plugin though.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  The problem with this approach is that this will result in the third entry (E) never appearing in the output.